# Substitute for running Vagrant and VirtualBox on M1 Apple Silicon

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, apple-m1

I currently have an almost perfect environment for local development using Vagrant and VirtualBox when working on Apple M1 chip (ARM-based). Configuration diagram as in the image below:

[Diagram preview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkf7d.png)

I am quite happy with this setup – doesn't take long to prepare. And what is most satisfying about such a solution is the code synchronization times - they are instantaneous, there is no noticeable delay - and the code compilation time. The latter, in the case of preparing a debian package, decreased from 12 minutes (with the standard use of VirtualBox locally) to 2.5 minutes!

More details:

- VPN service is running on Synology NAS
- Code synchronization uses Synology Drive

Do you have any insights or tips?

Comment: I'm trying to set something like this up but it I found that VirtualBox does not support running on an M1(Silicon/ARM) Mac. How did you achieve that?